# ASMedia USB 3.1 slow 4k Q32T1 speed

Tags: ssd, raid, usb-3

I have a RAID enclosure USB 3.1 Gen 2 with 2 SSDs inside.

The speeds I get on my ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard is strange.
I connected the same RAID to both USB 3 and USB 3.1 Gen 2 ports.

The speed that I get with USB 3.1 Gen 2 is slower than USB 3 in case of 4k Q32T1 as you can see from the image above. What gives? There is a problem with ASMedia drivers?

[image: USB 3.1 Speed Test]